# Autodocument function for C Code

Tags: yasnippet, elisp-macros, lisp

Suppose i have this line of code presenting a C function prototype:

```c
int sum_Func(int a, int *b)
```

I want an Emacs lisp function that adds the function description (initialization) according to its elements:

```c
    /**
    *sum_func-
    *@a:
    *@b:
    *Return:
    */
    int sum_Func(int a, int *b)
```

I'm new to Emacs.I tried to accomplish that with  recording a macro but the function 's number of  arguments is not fixed,which it makes a lisp function more suitable for the task.

Comment: Elisp tag doesn't apply here. Please read [Elisp tag info](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info)

Comment: [Doxymacs](https://sourceforge.net/projects/doxymacs/) did that , although is quite old now.